# How to disable blueprint view on Android Studio permanently?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

When editing layouts, my computer lags a lot when it shows both the Design and Blueprint views like so :

[image]

I can press that blue icon at the top left to disable Blueprint but I have to do it for every layout. Is there a way to permanently disable it for Android Studio?

Comment: Which `AS` version you are using . I am on `3.0.1` looks like  its auto saves the preferences .

Comment: I'm on 3.0.1 as well. It does auto-save when I change the setting for a particular layout file but it doesn't do it for all layout files. When I create a new layout file or open one that I hadn't opened before, the setting is still Design+Blueprint. Not a huge problem to turn off, was just wondering if there is a permanent way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do this just click on blue print design and press 'B' button and it will hide and you want it again then press "B" again and again.
hope it works..

Answer (score 0):

[image: You should choose Design. Not Design and BluePrint.]

You should choose Design. Not Design and BluePrint.